# Perform concat in pandas without including common column twice

Tags: python, pandas

From Pandas documentation:

`result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join='inner')`

[image]

How can I perform a `concat` operation but without including the common columns twice? I only want to include them once. In this example, columns `B` and `D` are repeated twice after `concat` but have the same values.

Comment: You could drop the columns from one of the dataframes before using `concat`.

Comment: `B` and `D` columns from both data frames are different. Which ones do you want to keep in the final result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the columns from `df4` that are not in `df1`:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df4[['F']]], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Or:

```
complementary = [c for c in df4 if c not in df1]
result = pd.concat([df1, df4[complementary], axis=1, join='inner')
```

The latter expression will choose the complementary columns automatically.

P.S. If the columns with the same name are different in `df1` and `df4` (as it seems to be in your case), you can apply the same trick symmetrically and select only the complementary columns from `df1`.